# Como leer un xml guardado en Base de datos sql

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, bootstrap, .net

Necesito poder leer todo los data de cada row para ponerlos en un **bootstrap-table**, alguien tiene alguna idea?

Tengo este codigo guardado en un campo de mi base de datos **sqlserver**:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
    <s:AttributeType name='Problem' rs:number='1' rs:nullable='true'                   rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
         rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Problem'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='150'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:AttributeType name='None' rs:number='2' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
         rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='None'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:AttributeType name='Mild' rs:number='3' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
         rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Mild'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:AttributeType name='Moderate' rs:number='4' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
         rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Moderate'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:AttributeType name='Severe' rs:number='5' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
         rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Severe'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row Problem='DEPRESSED MOOD' None='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='MOOD SWINGS' Mild='a' Moderate='g' Severe='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='IRRITABILITY'/>
    <z:row Problem='POOR CONCENTRATION' None='s' Moderate='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='AGITATION' Moderate='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='SLEEP DISTURBANCE'/>
    <z:row Problem='FATIGUE/LOW ENERGY'/>
    <z:row Problem='POOR GROOMING'/>
    <z:row Problem='GENERALIZED ANXIETY'/>
    <z:row Problem='PANIC ATTACKS'/>
    <z:row Problem='PHOBIAS'/>
    <z:row Problem='OBSESSIONS/COMPULSIONS'/>
    <z:row Problem='PSYCHOMOTOR DISTURBANCE'/>
    <z:row Problem='LOOSE ASSOCIATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEVERE PSYCHOMOTOR RETARDATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEVERE GRIEF'/>
    <z:row Problem='PARANOID IDEATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='DELUSIONS'/>
    <z:row Problem='HALLUCINATIONS'/>
    <z:row Problem='AGGRESSIVE BEHAVIORS'/>
    <z:row Problem='CONDUCT PROBLEMS'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEXUAL DYSFUNCTION'/>
    <z:row Problem='HOPELESSNESS'/>
    <z:row Problem='SOCIAL ISOLATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='WORTHLESSNESS'/>
    <z:row Problem='GUILT'/>
    <z:row Problem='ELEVATED MOOD'/>
    <z:row Problem='HYPERACTIVITY'/>
    <z:row Problem='DISSOCIATIVE STATES'/>
    <z:row Problem='SOMATIC-COMPLAINTS'/>
    <z:row Problem='SELF-MUTILATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='SIGNIFICANT WEIGHT GAIN/LOSS'/>
    <z:row Problem='CONCOMITANT MEDICAL CONDITION'/>
    <z:row Problem='EMOTIONAL/PSYCHOLOGICAL TRAUMA VICTIM'/>
    <z:row Problem='PHYSICAL TRAUMA VICTIM'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEXUAL TRAUMA VICTIM'/>
    <z:row Problem='EMOTIONAL/PSYCHOLOGICAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR'/>
    <z:row Problem='PHYSICAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEXUAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR'/>
    <z:row Problem='SUBSTANCE ABUSE'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

He intentado con esto pero no me ha resultado.

```
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM FooTable", connString);
da.Fill(ds, "FooTable");
dt = ds.Tables["FooTable"];

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dr["Column1"].ToString());
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Actualmente estás pidiendo que te desarrollen todo. Para que tu pregunta tenga un mejor alcance especifica lo que has intentado (esto es muy importante), la tecnología que tienes en el backend porque la implementación varía (ASP != ASP.net Webforms != ASP.net MVC != ASP.net Core). Por cierto, que no te sorprenda si te cierran la pregunta, a menos que la edites agregando los detalles mencionados. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que quieres hacer es leer lo que hay un XML junto con sus atributos, aquí tienes una respuesta:

```
using System;
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var doc = Program.GenerateXML();

        XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(doc));
        while (rdr.Read())
        {           
            if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(rdr.LocalName);
                if(rdr.LocalName == "row"){
                    var attr = rdr.GetAttribute("Problem"); 
                    var none = rdr.GetAttribute("None"); 
                    var mild = rdr.GetAttribute("Mild"); 
                    var moderate = rdr.GetAttribute("Moderate"); 
                    var severe  = rdr.GetAttribute("Severe"); 
                    Console.WriteLine("attr: " + attr + " none: " + none + " mild: "+mild + " moderate: "+moderate + " severe: "+severe);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GenerateXML() { 
        string xml =
        @" <xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
    <s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
        <s:AttributeType name='Problem' rs:number='1' rs:nullable='true'                   rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
             rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Problem'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='150'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='None' rs:number='2' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
             rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='None'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Mild' rs:number='3' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
             rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Mild'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Moderate' rs:number='4' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
             rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Moderate'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Severe' rs:number='5' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='MEDEZ_KAFERRY'
             rs:basetable='##Md431884276352444' rs:basecolumn='Severe'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='1'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row Problem='DEPRESSED MOOD' None='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='MOOD SWINGS' Mild='a' Moderate='g' Severe='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='IRRITABILITY'/>
    <z:row Problem='POOR CONCENTRATION' None='s' Moderate='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='AGITATION' Moderate='s'/>
    <z:row Problem='SLEEP DISTURBANCE'/>
    <z:row Problem='FATIGUE/LOW ENERGY'/>
    <z:row Problem='POOR GROOMING'/>
    <z:row Problem='GENERALIZED ANXIETY'/>
    <z:row Problem='PANIC ATTACKS'/>
    <z:row Problem='PHOBIAS'/>
    <z:row Problem='OBSESSIONS/COMPULSIONS'/>
    <z:row Problem='PSYCHOMOTOR DISTURBANCE'/>
    <z:row Problem='LOOSE ASSOCIATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEVERE PSYCHOMOTOR RETARDATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEVERE GRIEF'/>
    <z:row Problem='PARANOID IDEATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='DELUSIONS'/>
    <z:row Problem='HALLUCINATIONS'/>
    <z:row Problem='AGGRESSIVE BEHAVIORS'/>
    <z:row Problem='CONDUCT PROBLEMS'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEXUAL DYSFUNCTION'/>
    <z:row Problem='HOPELESSNESS'/>
    <z:row Problem='SOCIAL ISOLATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='WORTHLESSNESS'/>
    <z:row Problem='GUILT'/>
    <z:row Problem='ELEVATED MOOD'/>
    <z:row Problem='HYPERACTIVITY'/>
    <z:row Problem='DISSOCIATIVE STATES'/>
    <z:row Problem='SOMATIC-COMPLAINTS'/>
    <z:row Problem='SELF-MUTILATION'/>
    <z:row Problem='SIGNIFICANT WEIGHT GAIN/LOSS'/>
    <z:row Problem='CONCOMITANT MEDICAL CONDITION'/>
    <z:row Problem='EMOTIONAL/PSYCHOLOGICAL TRAUMA VICTIM'/>
    <z:row Problem='PHYSICAL TRAUMA VICTIM'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEXUAL TRAUMA VICTIM'/>
    <z:row Problem='EMOTIONAL/PSYCHOLOGICAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR'/>
    <z:row Problem='PHYSICAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR'/>
    <z:row Problem='SEXUAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR'/>
    <z:row Problem='SUBSTANCE ABUSE'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>";
        return xml;
    }

}
```

Esto da como resultado:

```
attr: DEPRESSED MOOD none: s mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: MOOD SWINGS none:  mild: a moderate: g severe: s
attr: IRRITABILITY none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: POOR CONCENTRATION none: s mild:  moderate: s severe: 
attr: AGITATION none:  mild:  moderate: s severe: 
attr: SLEEP DISTURBANCE none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: FATIGUE/LOW ENERGY none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: POOR GROOMING none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: GENERALIZED ANXIETY none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: PANIC ATTACKS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: PHOBIAS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: OBSESSIONS/COMPULSIONS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: PSYCHOMOTOR DISTURBANCE none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: LOOSE ASSOCIATION none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SEVERE PSYCHOMOTOR RETARDATION none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SEVERE GRIEF none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: PARANOID IDEATION none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: DELUSIONS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: HALLUCINATIONS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: AGGRESSIVE BEHAVIORS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: CONDUCT PROBLEMS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SEXUAL DYSFUNCTION none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: HOPELESSNESS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SOCIAL ISOLATION none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: WORTHLESSNESS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: GUILT none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: ELEVATED MOOD none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: HYPERACTIVITY none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: DISSOCIATIVE STATES none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SOMATIC-COMPLAINTS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SELF-MUTILATION none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SIGNIFICANT WEIGHT GAIN/LOSS none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: CONCOMITANT MEDICAL CONDITION none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: EMOTIONAL/PSYCHOLOGICAL TRAUMA VICTIM none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: PHYSICAL TRAUMA VICTIM none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SEXUAL TRAUMA VICTIM none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: EMOTIONAL/PSYCHOLOGICAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: PHYSICAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SEXUAL TRAUMA PERPETRATOR none:  mild:  moderate:  severe: 
attr: SUBSTANCE ABUSE none:  mild:  moderate:  severe:
```

Ver funcionamiento en DotNetFiddle.net https://dotnetfiddle.net/cJ1ZZR

Teniendo esto, lo demás te será sencillo. Buena suerte :D